# Hamburger creating a right facing arrow instead of a X

Tags: html, css

Creating a hamburger by following a tutorial online. The tutorial shows a X with the code given, when copied creates a right pointing arrow.

This is the HTML and CSS code for the Hamburger.

```css
.hamburger:hover span:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateX(10px);
  background-color: var(--primary);
}

.hamburger.is-active span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translate(0px, -2px) rotate(45deg);
}

.hamburger.is-active span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(15px);
}

.hamburger.is-active span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translate(-3px, 3px) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<button class="hamburger is-active">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</button>
```

Comment: you have to toggle the class by JavaScript

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to show an X or an arrow, are you sure you've included everything from the tutorial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the following changes to your code

1 - Add JavaScript code to toggle the `.is-active` class into the `.hamburger`.

2 - Add the default styling to `span`.

3 - Add the styling to `span`'s when `.is-active` is add to `.hamburger`

```js
const hamburgerMenu = document.querySelector('.hamburger');

hamburgerMenu.addEventListener('click', function() {
  hamburgerMenu.classList.toggle('is-active');
});
```

```css
.hamburger {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.hamburger:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

span {
  display: block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

.hamburger.is-active span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(6px, 5px);
}

.hamburger.is-active span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

.hamburger.is-active span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(6px, -5px);
}
```

```html
<button class="hamburger">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Your answer should contain some explanation of changes. See [answer].